# Trying to update git submodule with Ruby, how to chdir before executing shell command?

Tags: ruby, git, rake, git-submodules

I have some git repo X that has a submodule in the subfolder foo/bar pointing to repo Y.

I'm trying to get my CI system to update the submodule automatically, I mean pursuing this commands from RAKE:

```
$ cd foo/bar
$ git pull origin master
```

But when my RAKE task tries to perform this, it looks like it is pulling X instead of Y (from the log), so I assume the chdir to foo/bar didn't work.

What I've already tried in ruby:

1: Using backticks:

```
`cd foo && cd bar && git pull origin master`
```

2: Using Dir.chdir first and then backticks:

```
Dir.chdir(Dir.pwd + "\\foo\\bar")
`git pull origin master`
```

(Yes, I use backslashes because the agent runs on windows...)

Both methods above seem to still execute in X's root, instead of X\foo\bar.

Any ideas? :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not: `git submodule update`

Otherwise: `git --git-dir="foo\\bar" pull origin master`

Answer (score 1):

Pass `Dir.chdir` a block

```
Dir.chdir(Dir.pwd + "\\foo\\bar") do
    `git pull origin master`
end
```